# Django - Passing the model name to a view from url

Tags: django, url, view, models

How would I make it so I could pass the model name as a parameter in the url to a view? I would like to reuse this view and just pass the model name through to show a list of whatever model the parameter was.

Heres what I have so far

View

```
class ModelListView(ListView,objects):

    model = objects
    template_name = "model_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ModelListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['listobjects'] = model.objects.all()
        return context
```

URLS

```
url(r'^musicpack', MusicPackListView.as_view(), name='musicpack-list', objects = 'MusicPack'),
url(r'^instruments', MusicPackListView.as_view(), name='instrument-list', objects = 'Instrument'),
```

**ANSWERED**

Hey thanks for the answer

I've gone with the following and it seems to work.

View

```
class ModelListView(ListView):

    template_name = "model_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ModelListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

URLS

```
#models
from inventory.views import MusicPack
from inventory.views import Instrument
#views
from inventory.views import ModelListView

    url(r'^musicpacks', ModelListView.as_view(model = MusicPack,), name='musicpack-list'),
    url(r'^instruments', ModelListView.as_view(model = Instrument,), name='instrument-list'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pass perameter from urls to views like this:

VIEWS:

```
class ModelListView(ListView):

    model = None
    model_name= ''
    object = None

    template_name = "model_list.html" 

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ModelListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['listobjects'] = model.objects.all()
        return context
```

URLS:

```
url(r'^musicpack', ModelListView.as_view( model= MusicPackList,model_name= 'music_pack_list' object = 'MusicPack')),
url(r'^instruments', ModelListView.as_view( model=InstrumentPackList,model_name= 'instrument_pack_list', object= 'InstrumentPack'))
```